# Qt Linguist: Empty boxes instead of japanese glyphs

Tags: qt, fonts, translation

Trying to translate a Qt application to japanese, but Qt Linguist 5.2.1 on Xubuntu 14.04.4 LTS displays only empty boxes instead of japanese glyphs. Japanese translations in the *.ts XML files are correct, opening the *.ts files in Mousepad shows glyphs instead of empty boxes. So it is most likely a font issue. I can't find a way to change the font used by Qt Linguist.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the actual ja.ts, stripped down to just the term shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="ja_JP">
<context>
    <name>BackButton</name>
    <message>
        <source>Back</source>
        <extracomment>Generic Back button</extracomment>
        <translatorcomment>Google guess</translatorcomment>
        <translation>バック</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

Comment: Please provide example text or *.ts file so we could test on our side.

Comment: Added the ja.ts actually used.

Comment: Xubuntu was configured to use the "Redmond" Xfce theme and the "Raleigh" style, using the default font "Droid Sans". Changing that to "Liberation Sans" makes Linguist usable, but changes the font used in almost all other programs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Settings -> Appearance -> Fonts -> Default Font to "Liberation Sans" helps, but of course has a lot of side effects in other programs.

Comment: If when you say "Japanese" you mean you get empty boxes with kana (but kanji is fine), it's a known Qt bug, it's been fixed.